# define format of printf "%E"

Tags: bash, printf, scientific-notation

I work on a bash script and want to convert one input value, which is always an integer, to scientific notation. 
When I use printf "%E" for example, the value of 300 would be converted to 3.00E+02. In principle that make sense but I need the special format 0.300E+03. I didn't find a way to manage that.
Thanks for your help.

regards
helge

Answer (score 0):

One rude way, just to get started... **warning**: this works just for your example, with mantissa and exponent positive:

```
#!/bin/sh

theval=$(printf "%4.2E" "$1")   # 200 -> 2.00E+02
# we want 0.  20  E+03

mantissa=${theval%E*}
echo "mantissa1=$mantissa"  # 2.00
mantissa="0.${mantissa:0:1}${mantissa:2:1}"
echo "mantissa2=$mantissa"

exp=${theval#*+}
let exp=exp+1
exp=$(printf "%2.2d" $exp)

echo "Result=${mantissa}E+$exp"
```

Running this script yields:

```
/tmp$ ./exp.sh 200
mantissa1=2.00
mantissa2=0.20
Result=0.20E+03
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man 3 printf`, emphasis mine:

> `e, E` The  double  argument  is  rounded and converted in the style `[-]d.ddde±dd` where **there is one digit before the decimal-point character** and the number of digits after it is equal to the precision;  if the  precision  is  missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is zero, no decimal-point character appears.  An E conversion uses the letter E (rather than e) to introduce the exponent.   The  exponent always contains at least two digits; if the value is zero, the exponent is 00.

If you want the mantissa between 0 and 1, you'll need to build your own formatter. Here's an example in `awk`. Handles 0 and negatives:

```
function sn() {
    awk -vn=$1 'BEGIN {
    split(n,a,"E");
    if      (0 < a[1]) { m=a[1]/10; e=a[2]+1; p=length(a[1])-1; }
    else if (a[1] < 0) { m=a[1]/10; e=a[2]+1; p=length(a[1])-2; }
    else               { m=0; e=0; p=length(a[1])-2; }
    printf "%0.*fE%+03d", p, m, e;
    }'
}
```

Use like:

```
sn $(printf "%4.2E" -0.024)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers.
in principle it works, but when i have a number like 3180, just the first field of the number, the 3, is considered and not the rest of the initial number. I will try to find out the part of the code where the number of fields is defined.

regards
helge

Comment: I tried my answer with 3180, and it works almost reasonably. _Your answer above here should have been posted as a comment, not as an answer_.